# How to copy from storage account to localhost "windows" using Terraform

Tags: windows, azure, powershell, terraform

I'm looking for a way to copy from storage account azure to host machine Windows.

I can do it using `AZCOPY`.

But I need something with terraform once I create the machine, the copy will happen.

I found this option provisioner "file" but I can't precise storage account.

or if you have an idea to use it through powershell script

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Regarding "use it through powershell script", do you mean copy it to localhost? if yes, what do you want to copy, from blob storage or file storage?

Comment: I suggest you can use the VM extension with the PowerShell script to achieve it.